What I installed in the venv environment is installed globally
What I installed in the venv environment is installed globally
I tried the following steps, but it didn't solve the issue.
1
============
I entered the venv environment created with command 1 and installed the package with command 2.
1. python -m venv [venv name]

2. [venv name]\Scripts\activate


3. pip install [packege name]

============
2
============
Change the command to create a venv environment to the following command, according to the following site.
https://qiita.com/matata124/items/ba9e2abb6a6e8a350917
python -m venv --clear [venv name]

============
I tried to use both CMD and Powershell.
I activated the venv environment in Python and installed the library within it. However, even after deactivating the venv environment, the installed library can still be used.
Please teach me how I can solve the issue.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Creating an environment doesn't necessarily mean you're using it.   Did you do a [venv name]\Scripts\activate.bat?

After creating your virtual environment, you need to activate it before you can install any package.
python -m venv [venv name]
source [venv name]/bin/activate
pip install [packege name]

Alternative to activating the venv: run the pip command that is located in the ../venv/bin directory. It will use the python executable in the same directory and the python executable will know it is inside a venv, because it will find the pyvenv.cfg file in the parent directory.

After creating your virtual environment, you need to activate it before you can install any package.
For Mac/Linux
python -m venv [venv name]

source [venv name]/bin/activate

pip install [packege name]

For WINDOWS
python -mvenv [venv name]

[venv name]\Scripts\activate

pip install [packege name]


Thank you for your answer.
But I forgot to mention that I took the steps you mentioned.
What other causes could be possible in this case?
